# Why is the connection reset when uploading Wordpress plugin or theme on Ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

System OS:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

I have installed a LEMP stack:

```
nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
MySQL 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
```

The system is hanging and displaying a 'connection reset' error message in the browser when I try to upload a theme or a plugin.

I have managed to install some plugins from the Wordpress repository, but I can not install a 15MB plugin I am uploading via a zip from my remote machine via the browser.

I have increased the memory limit to 512mb by editing `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and the php.ini script is now reporting this is taking effect:

```
memory_limit    512M    512M
```

I have also increased the max memory limit in `wp-config.php`

by inserting this as the first line in the file:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

I have also created the following settings in the php config file at `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 240
max_input_time = 240
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Yet plugins or themes are still not uploading.

I have tried both Firefox and Chrome.

In Chrome, you get a % complete while the zip is being uploaded. The upload gets to 44% and then crashes, and I get the 'Connection Reset' error in the browser.

I have changed ownership of the plugin directory and wp-content directory to  `www-data:www-data`.

I don't know what else to try, any ideas?

Comment: Review this property `upload_max_filesize` in the `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` file, It must be equal or higher than 15M. Eg: `upload_max_filesize = 200M`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is already set, I will update the question.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate your configurations to the others `php.ini` files, just to check out?

Comment: No I haven't. Would you suggest running a search for php.ini across the server and overwriting any files that I find with the php.ini I have created at /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini ?

Comment: No, I only suggest to replicate **manually** the configurations related in your question, not all content, because it can cause some issues. Eg: `memory_limit`, `max_execution_time`, `max_input_time`, `upload_max_filesize`. I don't know if your development environment is an online server, but if it is a local server, have you thinked to try with Apache? If you consider that, remember make changes in the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` file. Also, you can try to copy the folder of the theme or plugin on the `wp-content` folder of wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and solve it by editing my htaccess, and it looks like this:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

# END WordPress
    # WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300

    php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
    php_value post_max_size 80M
    php_value max_input_time 300

</IfModule>
    php_value max_execution_time 3000
</IfModule>
```

1. Install the plugin "WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded" (It will help your files not breaking when uploading)
2. Then only add this part at the end of the htaccess:

   ```
   # WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded
   <IfModule mod_php7.c>
   php_value max_execution_time 300

   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_value post_max_size 80M
   php_value max_input_time 300

   </IfModule>
       php_value max_execution_time 3000
   </IfModule>
   ```

   Of course you can also change the numbers!

That helped me! Hope will help you also!

Atanas

Comment: Thanks Atanas, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I am using Nginx so the solution was different, but it was in the webserver config

Comment: Thanks! I'm happy to help you!

Answer (score 6):

As Atanas suggested in the answer posted for Apache, the problem was maximum file upload size in the web-server config.

To resolve the error in NGINX, I placed the following in the server block:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

(adjust to the size of your desired max upload size as required).

For example here is the full NGINX config I am running, with the above variable set:

```
{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! :)

Comment: @KengOnn That's great, pleased I added the NGINX version now, once I had translated it from the Apache answer!